# Como encontrar todos os números primos num conjunto de valores limitados?

Tags: python-3.x

Como encontrar **todos os números primos num conjunto** de `{ 1..100 }`?

**PS:** Após encontrar os determinados números, preciso **armazená-lo numa lista de resultado** (`result = []`).

```py
lista = []
result = []
cont = 0

for i in range(1, 1001):
    lista.append(i)
for j in lista:
    for i in range(1, 1001):
        if j % i == 0:
            cont += 1
            if cont == 2:
                result.append(j)
                cont = 0
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Erro de indentação, tente:

```
lista = []
result = []
cont = 0

for i in range(1, 1001):
    lista.append(i)
for j in lista:
    for i in range(1, 1001):
        if j % i == 0:
            cont += 1
    if cont == 2:
        result.append(j)
    cont = 0
print(result)
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda!